# Execute a python script without the shell

Tags: python, shell

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time , os
def execute():
    while True :        
        if not os.path.isfile("hello.txt"):
            fo = open("hello.txt","w");

execute()
```

Above code works properly when it is executed with command `python filename.py` but when as soon as shell is closed this execution is stopped. I wan to know is there any method to execute this script without using a shell(and execute continuously). I do not need to use cronjobs for this task.

thanks

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many method.

1. you can use:
   nohup python filename.py &
2. setsid python filename.py
3. use "screen"

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to create a daemon—a program that, when started, detaches and runs in the background.

If that's what you want, there are a lot of details to get right. [PEP 3143](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143) explains them. Fortunately, there's a [`python-daemon`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/) reference library that takes care of all the details for you. If you install that, all you have to do is what's shown in the example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time , os
import daemon

def execute():
    while True :        
        if not os.path.isfile("hello.txt"):
            fo = open("hello.txt","w");

with daemon.DaemonContext():
    execute()
```

The reason the example shows a separate wrapper script that does `from spam import main_program` is that it's very handy (at least for debugging) to be able to run the same program as a daemon and as a foreground script. But if you don't want that, you can do it all in one script.

(If that's not what you're asking, and you just want to know how to run any program in the background under Unix, that's more of a question for SuperUser than StackOverflow.)

Answer (score 0):

There are two available options that I know of and I personally use in **production**.

**the simpler option:**
http://www.tecmint.com/screen-command-examples-to-manage-linux-terminals/

**the better option where you want automatic restart during program crashes or system reboot:**
http://supervisord.org/running.html#adding-a-program